# How to pass info between Angular and C# ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, ajax

I am using ASP.NET (aspx) for the frontend of my web apps and C# as the backend & to talk to the database. However, I much prefer working with Angular for my frontend and it really quickens my development time.

My current knowledge of how to create web apps with .NET has a lot of ASPX code that communicates automatically with my C# code. However, I want my Angular/Javascript code to communicate with my C# (such as sending forms written in Angular to be posted by C# to my database).

I've heard I can use AJAX to do this, or special functions such as ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock. However, I am too inexperienced to intuitively find out how to make it work. Could someone please explain (with code examples from both sides) how this is done?

Comment: You can make AJAX calls to MVC REST services, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dd943053.aspx

Comment: You need a web service or at least some static WebMethod in your code behind and then call it using ajax. You can look for jQuery ajax method or if you don't use jQuery, google JavaScript XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: ajax call ->route ->controller->return data->ajax successful callback and you get all the data in a variable in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are not talking **ASP.Net Web Form** which cannot be used easily with AngularJS.

Many people use AngularJS with  **ASP.Net Web API**, but some leverage with ASP.Net MVC and Web API together.

I personally like **Mini SPA** (Silos). You can watch [AngularJS & ASP.NET MVC Playing Nice - Miguel Castro](https://vimeo.com/153759549).

You can also download the source at his [website](http://www.melvicorp.com/downloads.html).

***FYI:*** I also use [Angular.Net Helpers](https://axelzarate.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/angular-helpers-for-asp-net-mvc/) to generate strongly typed views. PluralSight has a course called [Strongly-typed AngularJS Apps with ASP.NET MVC](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/building-strongly-typed-angularjs-apps-aspdotnet-mvc5/table-of-contents).

Comment: time to edit this answer. The video is no longer available.

Comment: @Benjamin Thank you for letting me know. I updated the video link.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Angular, use the Angular libraries to communicate with your server-side code.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

or in case of a restful API:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Look into Asp.net Web Api for instance for your server-side code. Plenty of examples on google for this one.